# Python server store csv file sent from React client

Tags: javascript, python, file, python-requests, axios

As the title says, I have a client page that allows the user to upload files, they will always be .csv files.

```
export const sendFiles = async (files) => {
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append("arrFile", files);
  await axios
    .post(local + "/read-files", form, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
};
```

This is the code I have for sending the files, using FormData. The `files` is an array of `File` objects. It can have just one or many. The `files` array on console looks like this

```
Array [ File ]
    0: File { name: "filename.csv", lastModified: 1624560497968, size: 1244, … }
​​    lastModified: 1624560497968
    name: "filename.csv"
    size: 1244
    type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
    <prototype>: FilePrototype { name: Getter, lastModified: Getter, webkitRelativePath: Getter, … }
    length: 1
<prototype>: Array []
```

I'm sending this to my Python Flask server

```
@app.route("/read-files", methods=['POST'])
def read_files():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = dict(request.form)
        return
```

I found that the FormData is stored in request.form, but when I print this data on Python it shows as such.

```
{'arrFile': '[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File]'}
```

The files seem to be in a string separated by commas. What I'd like to do is be able to store these files and their content, and be able to read them afterwards. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
if {your_file_name} in request.files:
        file = request.files['your_file_name']
```

Comment: Hi @Asif, I tried checking the request.files, but it is an empty ImmutableMultiDict([]).